# Colormap is giving me multiple different colors

Tags: python, pandas, calendar, heatmap

I am making a calendar heatmap similar to github activity calendar. I am trying to color the calendar with one color if the event occurs and another color if the event doesn't occur. But, right now my calendar is plotted with multiple colors when the event occurs.

This is a screenshot of the data:
[image: Screenshot]

I don't want results like this, where there are light and dark greens when events occur on those dates:

[image: img]

I have tried using different colormap but nothing changed. Is there any ways to solve this?

```py
#some code here
.........
calmap.calendarplot(df_subset['event'], fillcolor='grey', fig_kws=dict(figsize=(15, 10)), cmap = u'Greens')
```

I want results like this, where darker greens mean event occurs:

[image: wanted]

Comment: This is probably due to the values in df_subset['event']. Can you add a screenshot in the post? If you want only two colors, there should be only two values (else it's a heatmap). The easiest fix would be to set the values in df_subset['event'] to 1 if one or more event happened or 0 if no event happened.

Comment: it is already set to 1 when events happen and 0 when no events happened

Comment: could you show what is in df_subset['event'] and maybe what should change from your first screenshot? (since you are giving a different one as a wanted result, I'm not sure I understand the problem)

Comment: i edited with a screenshot, it is the data corresponding to the first image

Comment: @SamuelToh do not post screenshots of your data. Copy and paste it here.

Comment: alright so many events can happen in the same day, which is why you are using a colormap. If you want a higher contrast between 1 event and 0: You cap the maximum amount of event that can happen in one day to a small number (like 3) so the colormap is not so stretched, or you can try to increment the distance between 1 and 0 (by setting all the 0 to -10 for instance). Another option would be to define a custom colormap. Also, if you don't have too many different values, directly assign colors instead of using a colormap

Comment: can you show me how? i am really new to this. or is there any websites i can look up to?